# How can I display the same html canvas in multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a web app that contains a map (Google Maps) in two separate tabs using twitter bootstrap. I'm trying to figure out a way to have one actual canvas that I can display in both tabs with different dimensions in each. The easiest way I can think of is to just have 2 maps and run the same updates on each whenever something changes. I don't like the idea of doing it that way though. Each tab uses the map in a slightly different way, but it should be the same map.

Is there a way to "bind" a div's content to another div?

Here is a simple code sample to explain what I'm doing:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#map1-content" data-toggle="tab">Map1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#map2-content" data-toggle="tab">Map2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="map1-content">(I want to display map canvas here)</div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="map2-content">(and I also want to put it here with this div's styling)</div>
</div>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of repeat the updates on each canvas, you can update the main canvas and after finish the drawing just draw back the main canvas into your styleshed canvas. I'll show you an example when I get more time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer the question:

It is impossible to display the same HTML canvas in multiple DIVs, full stop.

If you want to have the same map appear twice, you need to instantiate two separate canvases and run all updates to both.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bug after so long time... but could it be that this has changed during the last two years?
I need to do something similar as the qestioner here, but the solution with redrawing the original canvas to multiple ones sadly takes a lot of performance...